# I want to Install Wine without an internet connetion?

Tags: wine

I have Ubuntu 12.10, and I don't have any internet connection on my PC.

Please give me a Link for a Deb Package and Its DEPENDENCIES

How can I install wine without Internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a Terminal by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
sudo apt-get -qq --print-uris install wine | cut -d\' -f 2 > urls.txt
```

copy the `urls.txt` to a thumbdrive and move over to a computer with Internet Access. Download all files from `urls.txt` (if the other computer is running Linux you can use `wget < urls.txt`) and save them in a folder called `deb` on your thumbdrive.

Go back to your Ubuntu machine, plug in the thumbdrive and open a Terminal

```
sudo cp /media/YOUR_USERNAME/THUMBDRIVE_NAME/deb/* /var/cache/apt/archives/
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Comment: Ok...I've made the text file but it has only 1 deb file link >>>> will it work ??? i don't think it will work without dependencies !

Comment: It will list all dependencies which are necessary. I just double checked on a 12.10 VM where wine wasn't installed before and it listed 160 packages. Maybe you already installed wine? What does `dpkg -l | grep wine` print out?

Answer (score 0):

I have never installed it without an internet connection, but they have binary downloads at the homepage:

http://www.winehq.org/download/

and a good place to learn how to install software in different ways would be(that's where i started):

http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/linux-tutorials-howtos-reference-material/64958-how-install-software-linux.html

Answer (score 0):

[wine 1.5](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wine/files/latest/download?source=pdlp)

[wine 1.6](http://garr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/wine/Source/wine-1.6.tar.bz2)

First,download one of these file and then.
You will get file with *.tar.bz extention .
Extract it and you will find "read me" file. 
That particular file will guide you to install that software.

Answer (score 0):

How I did it(I guessed and naturally my guesses work) is i saved just the file not extracted to my drive. Okay. Then I plugged it into my other computer found where the file was.Right click, open as terminal. Then type in sudo apt-get install wine. Let me know if this works for you as well, its a shortened version of the top one.